# How to get the rows that contain 1 and col2 nonzero

Tags: matlab

For example:

```
x =

 1     0     0
 2     0     0
 1     2     0
 1     2     0
 2     1     0
 3     0     0
```

I want to get the rows:

```
y =

 1     2     0
 1     2     0
 2     1     0
```

They all **contain '1'** and **col2 != 0**.
Thanks!!!

Comment: ... show your effort?

Comment: Your last line is 50% of the way to valid syntax, try showing what you tried and why it's giving unexpected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
x(any((x == 1 & x(:,2) ~= 0),2),:)
```

In the above line:

```
x == 1
```

returns a matrix of the `logical` indices: `1`corresponds to the location where `x` is equal to `1`

```
x(:,2) ~= 0
```

returns a `logical` array with `1` when the value in the column 2 is different from `0`

Then

```
 x == 1 & x(:,2) ~= 0
```

returns a `logical` matrix with `1` when both the conditions are satisfied.

```
any((x == 1 & x(:,2) ~= 0),2)
```

returns a `logical` array with `1` when the above two condtions are matched in a row.

At the end,

```
x(any((x == 1 & x(:,2) ~= 0),2),:)
```

returns the rows of the initial matrix satisfying the desired cnsitions.

Comment: Note this only works for R2016b+, when implicit expansion was introduced. If you used `x(any(x == 1, 2) & x(:,2) ~= 0), :)` then you have something which works for all versions and is likely a touch quicker.

Comment: @Wolfie thanks for the hints, notice, there is a missing bracket in your proposal: `x(any(x == 1, 2) & (x(:,2) ~= 0), :)`

Comment: The joys of editing code in the comment window heh! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have to check every matrix row for two distinct conditions. This doesn't mean you have to do it using an iterative approach like using a `for loop`, since Matlab performs better when its computations are vectorized.

---

**Condition 1: the row contains at least one column whose value is equal to 1.**

This can be easily achieved using the [any function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html). You have to use the overload that accepts two arguments since, by default, `any` performs its computation on the first dimension of the matrix (columns):

```
any(x == 1,2) % 2 stands for the second matrix dimension (rows)
```

This will return a `logical` vector in which `true` values correspond to the matrix rows that respect the specified condition.

---

**Condition 2: the row values of the second column of the matrix must not be equal to 0.**

This can be achieved using a simple inequality operator applied to the second column of the matrix, as follows:

```
x(:,2) ~= 0
```

This will return a `logical` vector in which `true` values correspond to the rows that respect the specified condition.

---

**Final Result**

The final row indices are obtained combining the two indices obtained above, through an `and` logical operator (you want both conditions to be true):

```
cond2 = any(x == 1,2) & x(:,2) ~= 0;
```

Here is the full working code, in which the matrix rows are picked using the final indices:

```
x = [
 1     0     0;
 2     0     0;
 1     2     0;
 1     2     0;
 2     1     0;
 3     0     0
];

idx = any(x == 1,2) & x(:,2) ~= 0;
y = x(idx,:);
```

> y =
>
> ```
>  1     2     0
>  1     2     0
>  2     1     0
> ```